U.S. Treasury Securities : how to calculate net issuance
Treasury Security Auction Data
Each row represents a treasury auction:
>>> df[(df['issue_date'] >= '2024-03-01') & (df['issue_date'] <= '2024-03-20')][['issue_date', 'maturity_date', 'security_type', 'total_accepted']]
       issue_date maturity_date security_type total_accepted
9995   2024-03-05    2024-04-02          Bill    95096576100
9996   2024-03-05    2024-07-02          Bill    60060634300
9997   2024-03-05    2024-04-30          Bill    90090860300
9998   2024-03-07    2024-09-05          Bill    70275894100
9999   2024-03-07    2024-06-06          Bill    79311242700
10000  2024-03-07    2024-04-18           CMB    80000045200
10001  2024-03-12    2024-07-09          Bill    60060669400
10002  2024-03-12    2024-04-09          Bill    95094517100
10003  2024-03-12    2024-05-07          Bill    90091153900
10004  2024-03-14    2024-09-12          Bill    70293933600
10005  2024-03-14    2024-06-13          Bill    79331123700
10006  2024-03-14    2024-04-25           CMB    80001086200
10007  2024-03-15    2027-03-15          Note    56000018600
10008  2024-03-15    2054-02-15          Bond    22000030500
10009  2024-03-15    2034-02-15          Note    39000004400
10010  2024-03-19    2024-07-16          Bill    60061959000
10011  2024-03-19    2024-05-14          Bill    90091935800
10012  2024-03-19    2024-04-16          Bill    95097858000

Explanation of the columns

issue_date:    The date that the treasury security will be issued to the buyer
maturity_date: The date that the treasury security matures (buyer gets their money back)
security_type: Whether it's a bill, note, bond, etc.
total_accepted: The amount of total money brought in for the auction.

Net issuance
So, on any given day, for a particular security type (say bills) there may be some amount of issuance. But, there may also be some amount maturing. net issuance is:
net issuance = issued - maturing

Calculating net issuance
Here's a program which calculates a table of net issuance
import pandas as pd
import treasury_gov_pandas

df = treasury_gov_pandas.update_records('https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/auctions_query', lookback=10)

df['issue_date']    = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date']) 
df['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])

df['total_accepted'] = pd.to_numeric(df['total_accepted'], errors='coerce')

# group by 'issue_date' and 'security_type' and sum 'total_accepted'

issued = df.groupby(['issue_date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().reset_index()

# group by 'maturity_date' and 'security_type' and sum 'total_accepted'

maturing = df.groupby(['maturity_date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().reset_index()

# join issued and maturing on 'issue_date' = 'maturity_date' and 'security_type' = 'security_type'

merged = pd.merge(issued, maturing, how='outer', left_on=['issue_date', 'security_type'], right_on=['maturity_date', 'security_type'])

merged.rename(columns={'total_accepted_x': 'issued', 'total_accepted_y': 'maturing'}, inplace=True)

merged['change'] = merged['issued'].fillna(0) - merged['maturing'].fillna(0)

merged['date'] = merged['issue_date'].combine_first(merged['maturity_date'])

tmp = merged

agg = tmp.groupby(['date', 'security_type'])['change'].sum().reset_index()

pivot_df = agg.pivot(index='date', columns='security_type', values='change').fillna(0)

It uses the following library to retrieve the data:
https://github.com/dharmatech/treasury-gov-pandas.py
Notes
For any day:

There might only be issued securities
There might only be maturing securities
There might be both

Thus, in the code, I use an outer join.
Result
>>> pivot_df
security_type          Bill          Bond  CMB  FRN Note          Note     TIPS Bond  TIPS Note
date
1979-11-15     0.000000e+00  2.315000e+09  0.0       0.0  2.401000e+09  0.000000e+00        0.0
1980-01-03     6.606165e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
1980-01-08     4.007825e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
1980-01-10     6.402625e+09  1.501000e+09  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
1980-01-17     6.403760e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
...                     ...           ...  ...       ...           ...           ...        ...
2053-02-15     0.000000e+00 -6.635744e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00 -1.987600e+10        0.0
2053-05-15     0.000000e+00 -6.272132e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
2053-08-15     0.000000e+00 -7.160462e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
2053-11-15     0.000000e+00 -6.645674e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00        0.0
2054-02-15     0.000000e+00 -7.121181e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00 -9.389377e+09        0.0

There we can see, a column for each security type. The value for a given day shows the net issuance for that security type.
Question
This approach appears to work. But I'm wondering, is this considered idiomatic pandas code? Is there a better approach than this one?

Your code is all good, but if you want to further condense it, here is an approach. Since I did not have you required module installed, I attached the reuired function:
import pandas as pd
import os 
import time

def download_records_after(url, date, page_size=10000):
    data = []
    page = 1   
    url_params = f'?filter=record_date:gt:{date}&page[size]={page_size}'
    response = requests.get(url + url_params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result_json = response.json()
        data.extend(result_json['data'])

        while True:
            if result_json['links']['next'] is None:
                break
            else:
                response = requests.get(url + url_params + result_json['links']['next'])
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    result_json = response.json()
                    data.extend(result_json['data'])
                    page = page + 1
                    print(f'page {page} of {result_json["meta"]["total-pages"]}')

                    time.sleep(2)
                else:
                    print(f'status_code: {response.status_code}')
                    break
    else:
        print(f'status_code: {response.status_code}')

    return pd.DataFrame(data)

def update_records(url, start_date='1900-01-01', page_size=10000, path=None, lookback=2):
    
    if path is None:
        ls = url.split('/')[3:]
        path = '-'.join(ls).replace('_', '-') + '.pkl'
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print(f'Found {path}. Importing.')
        df = pd.read_pickle(path)
        recent_record_date = df['record_date'].unique()[-lookback]
        print(f'recent_record_date: {recent_record_date} lookback: {lookback}')
        new_records = download_records_after(url, recent_record_date, page_size)
        df = df[df['record_date'] <= recent_record_date]
        df = pd.concat([df, new_records], ignore_index=True)
        df.to_pickle(path)
        
        return df

    else:
           
        recent_record_date = start_date
        print(f'Using recent_record_date: {recent_record_date}')
        df = download_records_after(url, recent_record_date, page_size)
        df.to_pickle(path)
        return df
        
api_url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/auctions_query'

df = update_records(api_url,start_date='1900-01-01', page_size=10000, path=None, lookback=2)

df['issue_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])
df['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])
df['total_accepted'] = pd.to_numeric(df['total_accepted'], errors='coerce')

net_issuance = (
    pd.concat([
        df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])).groupby(['date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().rename('issued'),
        df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])).groupby(['date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().rename('maturing')
    ], axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .eval('net_issuance = issued - maturing')
    .reset_index()
)

pivot_df = net_issuance.pivot_table(index='date', columns='security_type', values='net_issuance', fill_value=0)

print(pivot_df)

which gives your expected output:
Found services-api-fiscal-service-v1-accounting-od-auctions-query.pkl. Importing.
recent_record_date: 2024-04-18 lookback: 2
security_type          Bill          Bond  CMB  FRN Note          Note  \
date                                                                     
1979-11-15     0.000000e+00  2.315000e+09  0.0       0.0  2.401000e+09   
1980-01-03     6.606165e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
1980-01-08     4.007825e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
1980-01-10     6.402625e+09  1.501000e+09  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
1980-01-17     6.403760e+09  0.000000e+00  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
...                     ...           ...  ...       ...           ...   
2053-02-15     0.000000e+00 -6.635744e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
2053-05-15     0.000000e+00 -6.272132e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
2053-08-15     0.000000e+00 -7.160462e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
2053-11-15     0.000000e+00 -6.645674e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
2054-02-15     0.000000e+00 -7.121181e+10  0.0       0.0  0.000000e+00   
...
2053-11-15     0.000000e+00        0.0  
2054-02-15    -9.389377e+09        0.0  

[4365 rows x 7 columns]

So, my contribution is simply
df['issue_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])
df['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])
df['total_accepted'] = pd.to_numeric(df['total_accepted'], errors='coerce')

net_issuance = (
    pd.concat([
        df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])).groupby(['date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().rename('issued'),
        df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])).groupby(['date', 'security_type'])['total_accepted'].sum().rename('maturing')
    ], axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
    .eval('net_issuance = issued - maturing')
    .reset_index()
)

pivot_df = net_issuance.pivot_table(index='date', columns='security_type', values='net_issuance', fill_value=0)

print(pivot_df)


This is impressive!  This sort of refactoring is what I was interested in seeing. Thank you!

Glad it helped! If you are pleased with the answer, do mark it as accepted so it disappears from the unanswered question. Happy coding!

I'd like to study the code first to make sure I understand it. Once I do, yup, I'll be glad to mark it answered.
